# Segregation rules for females studying in Saudi Arabia

Tags: masters, international-students, gender

Saudi universities are best in Middle East with nice modern programs and financing and scholarships. Unfortunately, as some of you may know, Saudi Arabia has special **segregation rules for women** entering the country (they must be followed by a guardian - male-relative or husband) and studying in colleges/universities.

What are **exact segregation-related conditions for a foreign woman to study in the Kingdom**? Can somebody here share their own experience? Not touching every university, but the situation in the country as a whole.

Comment: Some of the universities are effectively "compounds" in which the laws ruling the rest of the country are relaxed. For instance, the _abeya_ which women are obligated to wear outside is not required on the university campuses.

Comment: They are certainly well funded but far from the best in the Middle East.

Comment: Saudi Arabia has women's universities (i.e., for women only) that are actually quite decent.

Comment: @aeismail Thanks! But I'm afraid wearing a piece of clothes is far from being an important consideration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I myself study as a PhD student in King Abdullah University of Science and Technology (KAUST). It's a mixed-gender university. A single woman can study here without being accompanied by a husband.

It is a graduate-level university, that is, you can study only for Master of Science (MSc) or Philosophy Doctor (PhD) degrees here.

Regarding programs we have applied mathematics, computer science, electrical engineering, material science, Earth science, marine science, environmental science, statistics, mechanical engineering, chemistry, and many others (I'm not aware of all possible fields that are studied here).

You can find more information on the official website (https://www.kaust.edu.sa/en).